# I am trying to create a certain number of files in a folder using Python, but I have tried this method, but I cannot

Tags: python

```
import os

file_folder = open("D:\python")

for i in range(1, 51):

    file_name = f"txt{i}.txt"
    file_path = os.path.join(file_folder, file_name)
```

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\python'

Comment: The first line is wrong, move the `open()` statement where you have to open the file.
`file_folder = r"D:\python"`

Answer (score 0):

open function is used to open a file, not a folder.

```
for i in range(1, 51):
    with open(f"folder/path/{i}.txt", 'w') as f:
        pass
```

Comment: Working on my system. Make sure you update the folder path.